# 3 Phase Motor to DC Output

Tags: motor, generator, phase, electron

In a standard car alternator there is are 3 diodes that keep each of the phases from ever pulling electrons.
There is then a capacitor to smoothens it all out.
However how is it possible that the copper wires keep on supplying electrons without running out of electrons ?
See this link for an example circuit.

https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAlcYlcGmkNl5MhUcLSpIq06Ak7deYHuEIKxEGpLEpYxOsQRhIKbMWxKE9GHK5LeKTStqiqGrVRrQwePBmLHIGgw8QlNIKVk2ABMQB1d+QWxVMATeKIYAMwBDAFcAGwAXaNjHO0Tk5TTM3MLiuJKqbCSG2JB07PyigHc1FIF6vqg2HrKygeVIYbV6mcdJnqbVes1XCanFtRW1efK+AS2yybBCXgPlGkIBMbbqzqY8hhiIaShYdgBzWku1BBQ8baGQA

Comment: Hum ... Are you sure that there is only 3 diodes ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Nsa.png And capacitor is not "needed".

Comment: Electrons are running in circles, never come out of system. Ground is not earth, it is actually car body. Sometimes common wire called " ground".

Answer (score 2):

It's a pity that the Falstad simulation you linked has hidden the GND connections at the bottom end of each 40 Hz alternator phase winding. Then it would be apparent that the current flow through each diode, through the load, and through the load's GND connection was in fact returning to the windings through their GND connections.

Current always flows in loops, and the loop here is completed by the ground connections.

Notice I'm talking about current here, rather than electrons. The latter rarely give you any extra insight into what's happening, and then you might get hung upon the 'opposite sign' anxieties that plague so many early learners in electronics. At your stage of development, just think of current as current, and don't worry too much about what it's made of. If you go on to do electrochemistry or plasma physics, you'll meet positive and negative ions, or semiconductor material or device design then you'll meet electrons and holes, and you'll need to consider how they carry charge and the flow is a current. But for now, forget electrons and think current. After 40 years in the electronic engineering business and a dozen patents, I've never had to bother with electrons, ever.